# How to upload file using my mobile device (wordpress)(HTML)

Tags: wordpress, cordova

I use wordpress to establish a website than using phonegap to become a app,

but when I pressed upload file botton on my smartphone device I found out that it only works on computer because it don't know how to direct to the file storage in my smartphone

Anyone know how to upload file using my mobile device ?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit files unless your mobile device supports uploading local files.Some of the mobile phones won't support. 
refer these links [mobile file upload issues](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mobile-file-upload-issues) and [wp file upload](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/)

Comment: That's more suited to be a comment!

Comment: @GargAnkit I don't have enough reputation points to do a comment !

Answer (score 0):

When I use browser to open my wordpress site on my phone it works,but if I enter the website by app it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use File plugin for apache cordova:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

With it you can access files in your local storage.